# Fastest lookup and insert structure

Tags: javascript, performance, data-structures

I have a scenario where I need to check if a specific string exists, if it doesn't, then run some operation and insert the string as a key. I have used a `Set` for this. After running certain operations, I can see the `Set`'s size to be around 500 000. I would do roughly equal amount of lookups and inserts. Is `Set` a good option for this? Could something like a trie be a better option? Memory isn't of concern really, it's all about speed.

Comment: If a trie would be the best way to do it, I'd expect the `Set` implementation to use it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#As_a_replacement_for_other_data_structures